# a problem of leading data with HTTP?

Tags: vb.net

firstlly im sorry for my poor english

i have a problem with a chat application in vb.net
the problem is occuring when 
 i loading data from a XML file , my form is not responding.

i have a solution for that problem but i need other solutions

thank you

Comment: your question is far too vague to get precise answers. (Although Jon Skeet quite probably guessed correctly what the problem is.) -- Does your form stop responding forever (even *after* the XML is loaded), or is the form only non-responsive *while* your XML is loading? Why do you need more solutions -- or rather, what's wrong with your current solution?

Comment: its like the browser when leading a webpage , the form not stop reponde for ever just for the time when leading but i lead data every second and that like for ever , my sollution its leading data in a hide form by i want a better sollution and i think there are better , im new in vb.net :D

Answer (score 3):

Basically, you should either perform the IO in a separate thread using synchronous calls, or use asynchronous calls and handle events indicating progress etc. Using a separate thread is probably the simpler approach - and then use `Control.BeginInvoke` or `Dispatcher.BeginInvoke` to get the data back to the UI thread when it's finished loading.

*Don't* block the UI thread waiting for IO.